# Specified distinct columns only

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I wish to select two distinct columns and one normal. But it seems like the error of missing right parenthesis keep coming out when i already written properly.

Here's the sample code:

```
Select Distinct(F.DATE, F.EXAM_TIME), T.*
From Test T, ExamRecords F
Where T.TestNo= 10
And T.TestPaper = 'Science';
```

Thanks for any clarification given/mistakes that i have made~

Comment: How would you expect such a query to be returned, as you would have different number of records for different fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT wont work based on columns, it works on the entire row, you may want to use Group BY

Comment: Additionally: it is **not** a function. Writing `DISTINCT (col1, col2)` makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` can only be applied to the complete row in the query result.